# Start Quartz job in five minutes

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I would like to start a quartz job in five minutes. Be aware that I don't want to start the job EVERY five minutes but only AFTER five minutes.

Currently I'm using the following code but it does not work properly because the quartz job gets executed every 'intervalInMinutes' minutes:

```
     MutableTrigger trigger = (MutableTrigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInMinutes(intervalInMinutes).withRepeatCount(repeatCount)).build();
        return new Rule(trigger);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: If u want to run once only, then y r u using quartz. use some threading concept.

Answer (score 1):

Found answer. I used this code:

```
trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger() 
.withIdentity("trigger5", "group1")
.startAt(futureDate(5, IntervalUnit.MINUTE)) // use DateBuilder to create a date in the future
.forJob(myJobKey) // identify job with its JobKey
.build();
```